# Apache Wicket - push websocket component update while ajax request rendering

Tags: java, ajax, websocket, wicket

In our wicket application we have only a single page and every change on the page is done with ajax. But in some cases (e.q. we have to open a new database and initialize a JPA `EntityManagerFactory` etc. is taking some time) we push a customizeable "loading popup" (also a wicket component) via websocket to the client.

This works great but yesterday we ran into a problem. Until now we pushed the popup always before the actual rendering for the ajax request started(e.q. some navigation click in sense of component updates), but yesterday we pushed the popup in a component `onConfigure()` method so the building of the ajax request was already running.

As result the popup was, like always, immediately shown to the user and every component updated in the ajax request was renderd just fine except that all domready javascript of the components rendered before the websocket push are lost. So the wicket ajax click events of this components don't work, because in the `<evaluate>` tag of the response the javascript for this components is missing.

**What i already found out** with debugging is, that while rendering `AbstractAjaxResponse.writeHeaderContribution(Response, Component)` adds an `AjaxHtmlHeaderContainer` - holding the `IHeaderResponse` - to the page and when the push via websocket, another HeaderContainer with the same fixed wicket id (`"_header_"` defined in `HtmlHeaderSectionHandler.HEADER_ID`) is generated and replaces the first one, so the `IHeaderResponse` is lost before `render(HeaderItem)` is called for each `HeaderItems` and so are the scripts.

To my question: Is there any way to push component updates via websocket while an ajax request is running without running into the described problem? Or maybe is it a bug, because the updated component markup is correctly send to the client and only the scripts are missing?

**Edit:** we are currently using Wicket 6.15; changed `onBeforeRender()` to `onConfigure()`

**Edit2:** after upgrading to Wicket 6.24 the problem has changed: when the websocket request starts, it still replaces the `AjaxHtmlHeaderContainer` already added to the page. But after the websocket request is done, the header for the ajax request is still there, so the scripts are not lost. Now the entire request is correctly processed but in the finally statement from method `AbstractAjaxResponse.writeTo(Response, String)` the header is not null and the code tries to replace the header with a default header. And there is the problem, because of the websocket request the header is not any more added to the page and the replace code throws an exception that it cannot replace a component which has not been added.

Some additional information: the header is added to the page only on creation in `AbstractAjaxResponse.writeHeaderContribution(Response, Component)`, but after the websocket request the header of the ajax request is not null and so is not again added to the page.

**Edit3:** After writing a quickstart for the bug i tried it in Wicket 7.4 and there the problem does not occur

Comment: Please try out Wicket 6.24 - there where some issues solved with header rending, e.g. WICKET-5960.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I edited the question with the new resulting problem after upgrading to Wicket 6.24.

Comment: I don't see any relevant difference between 6.x and 7.x which would explain why it works in 7.x. Care to create an issue and attaching your quickstart?

Comment: I added an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-6246